# Sitefinity Mvc widgets are greyed out when dropped on the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sitefinity

This is on an out of the box Bootstrap 4 template that comes with Sitefinity with no additional styling or customization. When I drag and drop any Mvc widgets on the page, they're greyed out. The widgets can be edited but they won't show on the front-end when I publish the page.

When I drag the widget and drop it **below** the drop area (where the widget is not supposed to be dropped) then the widget becomes visible and not greyed out anymore.

Any idea why my widget areas are making my widgets greyed out? Below is an example, #1 is a greyed out widget which is dropped where it's supposed to be dropped. #2 is a the same widget which is dropped where it's not supposed to be dropped:

[image]

Comment: Aren't you supposed to drop them *inside* the areas? Why outside?

Comment: That's what I am puzzled about. The widgets get greyed out when they're dropped inside the area but they work fine when they're dropped outside.

Comment: That's weird. Have you changed the page template of this page? Does the issue occur on  newly created pages as well?

Comment: I am trying to upgrade to 13 to see if it resolves the issue